# Jenkins Github Plugin - Triggering a Parameterized Build

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a "Freestyle project" Jenkins job that has a single parameter--`GIT_BRANCH` so that I can trigger it manually or via a GitHub hook.

[image]

The problem is that the GitHub plugin doesn't seem to correctly identify / set the branch that was pushed.

When I look at the "GitHub Hook Log" view on the Jenkins build, I see (timestamps don't match because I've resent the hook);

```
Last GitHub Push

Started on Jul 5, 2016 11:37:01 AM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 7c4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (refs/remotes/origin/rc)
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h git@github.com:an-org/a-repo.git # timeout=10
Found 7 remote heads on git@github.com:an-org/a-repo.git
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/rc is: 7c4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx - already built by nnn
Done. Took 2.4 sec
No changes
```

Which is funny, because that's not the right branch at all, which I can confirm by looking at the GitHub hook log;

```
{
  "ref": "refs/heads/nil/jenkins-testing",
  "before": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "after": "27eyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
  "created": true,
  "deleted": false,
  "forced": true,
  "base_ref": null,
  "compare": "https://github.com/an-org/a-repo/commit/27eyyyyyyyyyy",
  "commits": [
    {
      "id": "27eyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
      "tree_id": "acebbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
      "distinct": true,
      "message": "dummy commit",
      "timestamp": "2016-07-05T11:13:59-07:00",
      "url": "https://github.com/an-org/a-repo/commit/27eyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
      "author": {
        "name": "Peter Novotnak",
        "email": "peter@novotnak.net",
        "username": "pnovotnak"
      },
      "committer": {
        "name": "GitHub",
        "email": "noreply@github.com",
        "username": "web-flow"
```

The logs from `com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubPushTrigger` `org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.WebhookManager` and `com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubWebHook` (ALL) show absolutely nothing.

I've tried the following as the name of the git parameter in place of "GIT_BRANCH";

- ref
- BRANCH_TO_BUILD
- BRANCH

Software versions:

- Jenkins - 2.11
- GitHub plugin - 1.19.2
- Git Parameter plugin - 0.5.1

Comment: did you get anywhere with this, having some issues myself

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I migrated most important things to ["Github Organization Folder Plugin"](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Organization+Folder+Plugin). I contributed to a thread on the Jenkinsci Users group, and got [this response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jenkinsci-users/-fSpEkbhpV4/Io1wQezcAwAJ) which suggests switching to the [Github Branch Source Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Branch+Source+Plugin) plugin, if not the Org. Folder plugin. Good luck!

Comment: Have seen similar problems of late, but I swore this was previously working when we were setup the same way as your job described. Maybe I'm dreaming.

We just changed `${GIT_BRANCH}`'s default value to `**`. Once we did, a push from github built a bunch of branches (since it was looking at all branches). Once it "caught up", it worked great - push built exactly the branch that had changed.

We did a manual build using a param and things got wonky again. I'm hoping an update to latest Github plugin might help.

Comment: I ended up in this state too. After a manual build with parameters it started working again. Very strange.