# Jenkins: how to use the Git Parameter and the Bitbucket Plugin simultaneously?

Tags: git, jenkins, triggers, bitbucket, webhooks

I have a job in Jenkins where I want to be able to do the following to:

1. **Automatically trigger a build** on a set of branches (`origin/master` and `origin/development`) whenever a new commit is pushed to them on Bitbucket.
2. **Manually start a build** with parameters with the specified git branch.

It is trivial to do 2. with the [Git Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin). For that, I created a parameter called `PARAM_GIT_BRANCH`.

For 1., I use the [Bitbucket Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin).

I was able to make both of them work **individually**:

- Manual build:

  - Create a `PARAM_GIT_BRANCH` git parameter in the *General* section
  - Put `${PARAM_GIT_BRANCH}` as "branches to build" in *Source Code Management* section
- Automatic build:

  - Put `*/master` and `*/development` as two items as "branches to build" in *Source Code Management*
  - Check off `Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket` in *Build Triggers* section

---

Now, here is the issue: **how to make both of them work together**?

- If I only put `${PARAM_GIT_BRANCH}` in "branches to build", then the Bitbucket webhook won't trigger the build (manual build works fine).
- If I only put `*/master` and `*/development` in "branches to build", then the manual build won't work (alas, the parameter wasn't even included there).
- If I put all three branches: `*/master`, `*/development` and `${PARAM_GIT_BRANCH}`, the build with parameters doesn't seem to be able to figure out the branch I specified. It just runs a build on the latest built branch (repeats the previous job build).

Possibly related: [Jenkins Github Plugin - Triggering a Parameterized Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211266/jenkins-github-plugin-triggering-a-parameterized-build)